# GLSL 1.2+ not supported on Mac OS?

Tags: c#, macos, opengl, opentk

I'm recieving the error

```
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '330' is not supported
ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
```

when trying to compile the following shader:

```
#version 330

in vec3 vPosition;
in  vec3 vColor;
out vec4 color;
uniform mat4 modelview;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelview * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);

    color = vec4( vColor, 1.0);
}
```

Re-writing the shader to version 110 spec compiles and runs fine:

```
#version 110

attribute vec3 vPosition;
attribute  vec3 vColor;
varying vec4 color;
uniform mat4 modelview;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = modelview * vec4(vPosition, 1.0);

    color = vec4( vColor, 1.0);
}
```

This worked for a while, but now I need to use 330 features.

I'm on a 2011 MacBook Pro running El Captian 10.11.2 and using the latest versions of `OpenTK.dll` and `OpenTK.dll.config` from the OpenTK website.

I have tried enabling the SDL2 backend by copying `libSDL2.dylib` from `opentk/Dependencies/x86` to my application directory as suggested by another user, but no difference.

What must I do to support 330 features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All MacBook Pros support at least OpenGL 3.3. The issue was in the defaults for OpenTK's GameWindow constructor. Their official documentation seems to imply that it defaults to OpenGL 2.1, but it definitely doesn't behave that way on Windows.

Adding this override fixed it.

```
public Game() : base(800, 600, new GraphicsMode(new ColorFormat(8), 3, 3, 4), "Welcome To Hell", GameWindowFlags.Default, DisplayDevice.Default, 3, 0, GraphicsContextFlags.Default)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly MAC driver on the latest OS have some issues with declaring of versions like 330.In fact from my experience it  was GL 3.2 and then they added the support for 4.1 on Maveric and other latest OS releases. You can just use 410 because this is the current highest GL profile MAC OS X uses and of course it should export all the core extensions from 330.

Comment: My problem is I can't just use 410 or 330. It spits `version '410' is not supported`

Comment: What is your hardware and OS version? have you checked what GL version it supports? Install some GL caps viewer and see what you get there.

Comment: Also,if it spits 410 is not supported then 330 is not supported as well.Because before GL4.1 Apple had GL3.2 as the latest version

Comment: Running El Capitan 10.11.2 with an Intel HD Graphics 3000 card, definitely supports 4.1.

Comment: Got it working by overriding the constructor. It was a problem with the Mac OS defaults.

Comment: That's not entirely true. There are a whole bunch of hardware configurations that support 3.3, but not 4.1. See the top row in the table here: https://developer.apple.com/opengl/capabilities/.